# Twilio taskRouter js sdk giving CORS error

Tags: twilio, twilio-taskrouter

Tried doing a worker.update(...), worker.completeTask(...) and always getting a CORS error from localhost.

[image]

Comment: Does [this thread on GitHub help at all](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/issues/574)?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this Policy to your back end. There is apparently a "bug" in the example code that Twilio provides and it has yet to be fixed.

This code is assuming a Node backend but the equivalent should work in any language

```js
// Worker Activity update policy
new Policy({
    url: util.workersUrl(workspaceSid, workerSid),
    method: 'POST',
    postFilter: {ActivitySid: {required: true}},
    allow: true,
  })
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. *walked away glazing into emptiness. twilio...*